# How to Get Latitude and longitude using Xamarin.Essentials?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to get lat and long using the `Xamarin.Essentials` package but I'm getting an exception

> exception: this functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly. you should reference the nuget package from your main application project in order to reference the platform-specific implementation. at xamarin.essentials.geolocation.platformlocationasync" 
>   i installed the package to every platform

Here is my code:

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Medium);
        var location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(request);

        if (location != null)
        {
            latitude.Text = location.Latitude.ToString();
            longitude.Text = location.Longitude.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (FeatureNotEnabledException fnex)
    {

    }
    catch (PermissionException perex)
    {

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Error3", ex.ToString(), "ok");
    }
}
```

Comment: try removing and reinstalling the nuget package in each project

Comment: @Jason i've tried that but still getting the same exception

Comment: What version of Android are you targeting?

Comment: @JamieRees Minimum Android version: Android 4.4(API Level 19), Target Android version: Android 6.0(API Level 23)

Comment: Are you using `.Net Standard` or `PCL`?

Comment: it woks for me,i use  Minimum Android version: Android 4.4(API Level 19), Target Android version: Android 6.0(API Level 23),and Target Framework :Android 8.1,only add the Xamarin.Essentials package in PCL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this issue report: https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/379

You need to set your Compile Target Version to Android 8.1

Answer (score 0):

As of March 2019, any apps targeting Android version lower than API-26(8.1) will not be accepted by Play store(Same reason for above exception), so I suggest you update that.

Also, your Device range fits the criteria so that is not the issue(see below),

> `Xamarin.Essentials` is focused on the following platforms:
>
> - iOS (10+)
> - Android (4.4+)
> - UWP (Fall Creators Update+)